# Python: Is there a performance difference between `dist` and `sdist`?

Tags: python, performance, setuptools

Python `setuptools` can create a source distribution:

```
python setup.py sdist # create a source distribution (tarball, zip file, etc.)
```

Or a binary distribution:

```
python setup.py bdist   # create a built (binary) distribution
```

As far as I understand, there should not be any performance difference:

- `bdist` installs the already-compiled `.pyc` files from the binary package.
- `sdist` compiles the `.py` files to `.pyc` files, and installs them.

When executed it should not matter how were the `.pyc` files compiled - they should have the same performance.

**Is there any performance difference between `dist` and `sdist` python packages?**

Comment: Have you done any measurements?

Comment: @merlin2011 not yet. I want to figure out the theory before running actual tests. Besides, the performance difference can be manifested in edge cases which I won't encounter.

Comment: Are you trying to establish the performance of the long tail, or the average case?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to figure out whether it's safe to base my deployment pipeline on `sdist` packages. If there is a slight chance that performance will be affected, I will make the extra effort to create binaries in my local repo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a pure Python code, the difference in time deploying will be slim. Note that there is no difference in performance between `.py` and `.pyc`, except that the latter will be read slightly faster the first time. The so called *optimised* `.pyo` only strip the asserts, and optionally, get rid of the docstrings, so they are not very much optimised.

The big difference comes when you have C files. [sdist](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html) will include them if properly referenced, but the user will need a working and appropiate compiler, Python header files, and so on. Also, you will have to take the time to build them on every client. The same distribution will be valid for any platform you deploy in.

On the other hand, [bdist](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html) compiles the code once. Installing in the client is immediate, as they don't need to build anything, and easier as they don't require a compiler installed. The downside is that you have to build for that platform. Setuptools is capable of doing cross-compilation, provided you have installed and configured the right tools.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It means that the source of my performance troubles is not `sdist`, so I will keep using it.

Comment: @AdamMatan I bet a carrot it is not. If your deploying is too slow, maybe you are compressing things too much (CPU client bound) or too little (network bound).

Comment: The problem is not the deployment process (which is fairly fast), but the server performance

Comment: @AdamMatan profile! Also, move the heaviest computations to Cython. A little bit of C code can do wonders!